# DropzoneJS Preview Image fill the whole container

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am using a theme which uses Dropdown.js to upload files.

The JS file is over 1000 Lines and I feel a bit lost.

What I am trying to achieve is that I have a container where you drop a file. I want that when you choose an image the image will appear as a preview in the same container. Right now when I upload an image the preview is a small 100x100 picture. I want it to fill out the whole content and be able to upload 1 image only.

I am not able to achieve it as I am pretty new and the big js file is confusing me. If someone can point me in the right direction it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching in the wrong file, your js controls the user experience. You need to work in the css of the dropzone, and add a width auto, height auto. Now to upload only one file that goes in you specifications of your dropzone, max-file: 1.
Check the documentation.

https://www.dropzonejs.com/